# Checking if current visitor is logged in to Joomla's backend

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I would like to keep Joomla from including tracking code for Google Analytics when I am logged in to the backend. For this purpose I am trying to determine whether a user who is browsing the website is also currently logged in to Joomla's backend. The problem is - when I use methods like `JUser::getAuthorisedGroups()` or `JUser::getAuthorisedViewLevels()`, Joomla's frontend still recognizes me as an unregistered guest.

I know Joomla keeps separate information about the current user for backend and frontend. But is there a way around it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logging in to the admin and viewing the front end both start independent sessions that are not related so using getUser() is only going to return the info for the current session.

Luckily, there are a couple of options. First, you can block your IP from being tracked in GA. Second, you can log in to the front end, then use a plugin to filter out logged in admin users.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I will have to try out these alternatives. However it is really strange that a front-end template cannot read session info for Joomla's back-end. I could imagine many use cases in which the front-end behavior is influenced by who is logged in to the back-end. I was pretty sure it was a natural thing any CMS should be capable of doing.

Comment: i think you can get this info from session table (jos_session)of joomla for logged in userid you can get every logged in user session and get logged in user in front end and backend . it's really help you. get all row form session table for count logged in user except guest

Comment: @Rakesh Yes, you can get the session data for logged in users from the DB, but how are you going to know which session also belongs to the user on the front end if they are not logged in?

Michal I would imagine that the reason Joomla separates front/back end sessions is so admins can see what a user sees without having to log out. If both sessions where the same, you would always get the admin view, which can be very different.

Comment: @Brent, I agree there are many scenarios for which both sessions being separate are very practical, I am just surprised that apparently there is no way to somehow get the information I need using Joomla Platform's API in front end templates. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: hey Brent, you can get user by userid of session table and admin by username or adminid of your user table and then check logged in user with userid match.

Comment: @RakeshSharma the problem is that there is no userid on the front end session since they are not logged in. If the user was logged in, you would already know that they were an admin.